# How to customize the 'node content links' block?

Tags: organic-groups, users

I'm using Organic Groups to make groups, and have made two content types to be added to the groups. I'm also using the OG extras module, so now I have the 'Node content links' block, where users may add content to the group. I want some of the users to see one of the links to create one content type, and the other users to see the other link to create the other content type.

How am I able to do this? Do I need to use organic group roles? If so, I'm unable to find out where I set this type of role for a member. I know where I can create them, but not assign them.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for this myself and come across this link:
http://makandracards.com/jan0sch/11463-drupal-organic-groups-extras-add-content-links

If you're using Drupal 7 and Organic Groups (2.x) you probably have the OG extras module enabled.

The documentation to enable the "create content" links for your organic group nodes is sparse. Therefore a short howto:

- Enable all needed modules Enable the module entityreference
  prepopulate!
- Go to "Structure" -> "Content types" and select your
  group content type, not your group type.
- Click on "manage fields" and edit the field "og_group_ref".
- Enable the checkbox labeled "Enable Entity reference prepopulate".
- Enable the block named "Node content links".
- Now you should be done. Steps 4-5 are needed for every group
  content type in case you have multiple content types that can be
  posted to groups.